# pandas: How to applymap in a for loop

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a python script that reads raw data from `Provsvar-fixed.xlsx`

[image]

and pick up columns and save to `Provsvar-summary.xlsx`.

These concerned columns are defined in `config.xlsx` something like this:

[image]

When writing to `Provsvar-summary.xlsx`, the cell will be highlighted if a cell value in `Provsvar-fixed.xlsx` not in the range (`LabReference.min`, `LabReference.Max`) (defined in `config.xlsx`)

The script below works well, but it is ugly, because there are so many boilerplate code `.applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[1]), subset=[lab_references[1].name])`.
If want to add a new line to `config.xlsx`, I have to add a new line script code `.applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[23]), subset=[lab_references[23].name])`, which is annoying.

```py
import pandas as pd


origin_provsvar = 'Provsvar-fixed.xlsx'
output_file = 'provsvar-summary.xlsx'
config = pd.read_excel("config.xlsx")


class LabReference:
    def __init__(self, name, min, max):
        self.name = name
        self.min = min
        self.max = max


# Provsvar-fixed
provsvar = pd.read_excel(origin_provsvar, sheet_name='Sheet1')

bad_style_low = 'background-color: #FFFB00'
bad_style_high = 'background-color: #FFC7CE'


def get_style(val, lab_reference):
    if not isinstance(val, int) and not isinstance(val, float):
        return ''
    if val < lab_reference.min:
        return bad_style_low
    elif val > lab_reference.max:
        return bad_style_high
    else:
        return ''


lab_references = []
for i, row in config.iterrows():
    '''
    Name                                Min Max
    Datum       
    S-ACE (E/L)                         0   70
    P--25-OH Vitamin D2+D3 (nmol/L)     50  250
    S-1,25-OH-Vitamin D (pmol/L)        48  190
    ......
    
    '''
    lab_item = LabReference(row['Name'], row['Min'], row['Max'])
    lab_references.append(lab_item)


for row in provsvar.index:
    for lab_item in lab_references:
        value = provsvar[lab_item.name].at[row]
        if isinstance(value, str):
            # Fix abnormal cell: "0,33, 0,33", convert "," to "."
            provsvar[lab_item.name].at[row] = float(value.split(", ")[0].replace(",", "."))

headers = list(map(lambda x: x.name, lab_references))

provsvar_new = pd.DataFrame(provsvar, columns=headers)


# ugly code 
provsvar_new.style.set_properties(**{'background-color': 'white',
                                     'color': 'black',
                                     'border-color': 'black',
                                     'border-width': '1px',
                                     'border-style': 'solid'}) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[1]), subset=[lab_references[1].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[1]), subset=[lab_references[1].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[2]), subset=[lab_references[2].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[3]), subset=[lab_references[3].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[4]), subset=[lab_references[4].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[5]), subset=[lab_references[5].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[6]), subset=[lab_references[6].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[7]), subset=[lab_references[7].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[8]), subset=[lab_references[8].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[9]), subset=[lab_references[9].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[10]), subset=[lab_references[10].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[11]), subset=[lab_references[11].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[12]), subset=[lab_references[12].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[13]), subset=[lab_references[13].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[14]), subset=[lab_references[14].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[15]), subset=[lab_references[15].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[16]), subset=[lab_references[16].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[17]), subset=[lab_references[17].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[18]), subset=[lab_references[18].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[19]), subset=[lab_references[19].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[20]), subset=[lab_references[20].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[21]), subset=[lab_references[21].name]) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[22]), subset=[lab_references[22].name]) \
    .to_excel(output_file, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='summary', index=False)

# ugly code 
print("complete")
```

I tried to replace the `# ugly code` by putting the `applymap` in a for loop like below, but it didn't work at all.

```
for lab_reference in lab_references:
    print(lab_reference.name, lab_reference.max)
    provsvar_new.style.set_properties(**{'background-color': 'white',
                                         'color': 'black',
                                         'border-color': 'black',
                                         'border-width': '1px',
                                         'border-style': 'solid'}) \
        .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_reference), subset=[lab_reference.name])

provsvar_new.to_excel(output_file, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='summary', index=False)
```

I am new to pandas, hope someone can help me figure out how to simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Range for your loop like so:

```
for i in range(0,23):

    provsvar_new.style.set_properties(**{'background-color': 'white',
                                 'color': 'black',
                                 'border-color': 'black',
                                 'border-width': '1px',
                                 'border-style': 'solid'}) \
    .applymap(lambda x: get_style(x, lab_references[i]), subset=[lab_references[i].name])


provsvar_new.to_excel(output_file, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='summary', index=False)
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? does it crash or just nothing happens?
did you try to add "to_excel" after you finished the loop?

Comment: Nothing happens, the code is here: https://github.com/zhihuitang/provsvar

Comment: thanks, it still doesn't work. I think the problem is that `to_excel()` must always tag along with `applymap()`, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
        provsvar_new.style.set_properties(**{'background-color': 'white',
                                         'color': 'black',
                                         'border-color': 'black',
                                         'border-width': '1px',
                                         'border-style': 'solid'}) \
.apply(lambda x: x.map(lambda y: get_style(y, config[config.name == x.name])))
```

Hope this works. This is shorter and dynamic but, still ugly, i guess.
to improve, you could have the get_style func accept col as arg and iterate over the values.

Comment: and `to_excel()` after the for loop? doesn't work, thanks